# How to change ownership in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, computer-name

I recently got a new comp and gave my not so old one to my hubby. It is obviously all in my name, so I am wondering how to change the name of my computer and root and everything from my name and username and password to his.

He changed the display name and password, but when the screen goes to sleep and asks for the password, it says "my username" on "my computer name" but still unlocks with the hubbys password. Help?  I know that I did all the naming during the install, and I don't really wanna have to transfer everything to do a clean install, so I'm hoping there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

First, read my answer (at least the bold parts), and then act. Since you may want to keep your old files. Or not. There is a computer name (hostname., a username, and a password for that user. Different terms. Read on.

**To change the computer name:**
1. Fire up a terminal.
2. Type: `sudo gedit /etc/hostname`
3. Edit the file according to your need, and save it. Close the editor, you are done. (It'll change after a reboot.)

**To change the username:**
1. Open up the dash (top-left), and search for "User accounts".
2. There is a "Locked" text somewhere. Click on it, it'll ask for your password.
3. Create a new Administrator account.
4. Login to the new one, delete the old one.

**! IF ! you want to transfer every setting and stuff from user X to user Y:**
1. Fire up a terminal.
2. type: `sudo apt-get install mc`
3. (when the previous one is done) type: `sudo mc`
4. Now, `mc` is a two-pane based file commander. You select files with Insert, and copy them with F5. What you have to do, is copy all the stuff, from folder `/home/userX` to `/home/userY`.
5. (you can switch the sides with TAB) Simply navigate the left side, to userX (old one), and the right side to userY (new one). When you are done, use the Insert key, to select all the stuff from the old user. Press F5 when you are done. Enter to confirm.
6. It'll start copying. May take some time.
7. Finally, you need to exit `mc`. To do that, press F10. (Or `Esc` and then `0`.
8. When you are in the Terminal, again. Type: `sudo chown -R userY:userY /home/userY`
(Of course, userY is the new user, who you just made for the new owner.)

Comment: This is the easiest way I know. There may be a software to do all this. But ... it never hurts to learn some linux "magic".

Answer (score 0):

@Shiki's answer is good, but a faster way to accomplish the file transfer would be (in a terminal, assuming your username is `daisy` and the new admin account you created is `hubby`):

```
sudo -s
cp -arvP /home/daisy /home/hubby
chown -R hubby:hubby /home/hubby
```

which requires no extra tools like `mc` and will also copy the hidden "dot" folders like `.gnome`, `.cache`, etc.

The `-arv` flags for the `cp` copy command are respectively `a`rchive (preserves permissions, file modification times, etc), `r`ecursive (copies all folders and subfolders), and `v`erbose (tell you the name of every file being copied.)

Edit: Add the `-P` flag to `cp` to prevent it following symbolic links, which is usually a bad thing. (`~/.gvfs` is an example - it contains symlinks to external/network drives.)

Comment: Hmm thanks, that will come handy. By the way ... why there is no simple utility for this? Just a simple GTK app.

Comment: Because you can accomplish it with three or four terminal commands. `useradd` adds new users; `cp -arvP` to copy the files; and `chown` to change ownership permissions.

Answer (score 0):

An even better way to do exactly what you want (which is change the username, and nothing more) is to use the appropriately named `usermod` (`mod`ify `user`) command, something like:

```
sudo usermod daisy -dm /home/hubby
sudo usermod daisy -l hubby
```

Google strategy: `linux change username` to give [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-rename-user-name-id/) (good stuff in the comments too.)

Addendum: excerpt from `man usermod`:

```
   -l, --login NEW_LOGIN
       The name of the user will be changed from LOGIN to NEW_LOGIN.
       Nothing else is changed. In particular, the user's home directory
       name should probably be changed manually to reflect the new login
       name.

   -d, --home HOME_DIR
       The user's new login directory.

       If the -m option is given, the contents of the current home
       directory will be moved to the new home directory, which is created
       if it does not already exist.
```